# Automatically Append Decimals in Ant Design InputNumber Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design's InputNumber component in a React project to create a custom money input field. The component formats input values with a thousand separator (e.g., "1.234" for one thousand two hundred thirty-four) and a comma as the decimal separator (e.g., "1.234,23"). The formatting works well when a user enters both integer and decimal values. However, I've encountered a challenge: when a user inputs a number without specifying any decimal digits (e.g., entering "1234" instead of "1234,00"), I want the component to automatically append ",00" to the input value once the user has finished typing, indicating zero cents in a user-friendly way.

```
import React from 'react';
import { InputNumber, Input } from 'antd';
import { TextInput } from '../input/TextInput';
import { formatMoney } from './MoneyFormatter';
import './MoneyInput.scss';

type MoneyInputProps = {
  value?: number;
  readOnly?: boolean;
  onChange?: (value?: number) => void;
};

export const MoneyInput = ({ value, readOnly = false, onChange, ...rest }: MoneyInputProps) => {
  const handleNumberChange = (newValue: string | number | null | undefined) => {
    if (onChange) {
      const value = Number.isFinite(newValue) ? newValue as number : undefined;
      onChange(value);
    }
  };
  if (readOnly) return <TextInput readOnly value={formatMoney(value)} {...rest} />;
  return (
    <Input.Group className='MoneyInput'>
      <InputNumber
        className='money-value'
        min={0}
        precision={2}
        value={value}
        decimalSeparator=','
        formatter={value => {
          const valueString = `${value}`;
          const [integer, decimal] = valueString.split('.');
          const formattedInteger = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
          return decimal ? `${formattedInteger},${decimal}` : formattedInteger;
        }}
        parser={value => value ? parseFloat(value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.')) : 0}
        onChange={handleNumberChange}
        {...rest}
      />
      <span className='ant-input-group-addon'>€</span>
    </Input.Group>
  );
};


My question is, how can I modify the formatter function (or perhaps use another approach) to automatically append ",00" to the input value if the user enters a number without decimals? I'd like this to happen once the user has finished typing, to ensure the displayed value always represents a complete monetary amount, including cents, in a format like "1.234,00" for consistency.

Note: I'm looking for a solution that integrates smoothly with the existing InputNumber component and its formatting capabilities, without introducing significant complexity or external dependencies.


I've tried adjusting the formatter function within the InputNumber component to include a check for the presence of decimal points in the user's input. My initial approach was to split the input value by the decimal separator and check if the decimal part exists. If not, I attempted to append ",00" to the string. Here's a simplified version of what I attempted:
```

Comment: I would suggest you look into `debounce`. You can create your own `debounce` function or you can use library like `lodash`